# Get type of class for array from TypeMirror

Tags: java

I am doing Java APT and want to parse a method (an `ExecutableElement`). Now I need the return type of the method. I do not know how to get the type, if it is an array.

Example: `String[] foobar()`

I want to get the type `String`.

From the ExecutableElement instance, I can get the return-type as an instance of TypeMirror (using `getReturnType()`). But if it is an array, I can not get the "real type" (in my example: `String`).

I tried:

```
System.out.println("TEST: " + pReturnType.toString());
System.out.println("TEST2: " + pReturnType.getClass().getName());
System.out.println("TEST3: " + pReturnType.getClass().getEnclosingClass());
System.out.println("TEST4: " + pReturnType.getClass().getComponentType());
System.out.println("TEST5: " + pReturnType.getKind());
```

Which gives me:

```
TEST: java.lang.String[]
TEST2: com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$ArrayType
TEST3: class com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type
TEST4: null
TEST5: ARRAY
```

I would like an instance of `java.lang.Class`, representing `java.lang.String` (in my example).

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old question but all the answers here are considering reflection and not TypeMirror which is part of the annotation processing api and not reflection.

To get the component type from a typeMirror you must cast it into `ArrayType` and call the method `ArrayType::getComponentType()` i.e.,

```
TypeMirror pReturnType = ...
if (pReturnType.getKind() == TypeKind.ARRAY) {
    return ((ArrayType)pReturnType).getComponentType();
} else {
  //this is not an array type..
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Method "getComponentType" is worked fine:

```
public String[] getValues() {
    return null;
}

@Test
public void testIt() throws Exception {
    Method m = this.getClass().getMethod("getValues");
    if (m.getReturnType().isArray()) {
        System.out.println(m.getReturnType().getComponentType());
    }
}
```

Output is: class java.lang.String

Comment: "Method" is another type then "TypeMirror". I dont have an instance of type "Method" but of type "TypeMirror". Java APT (Annotations Processing) does not seem to use classic reflection. It gives me instances of type javax.lang.model.element.Element, like ExecutableElement (not: java.lang.reflect.Method) for methods.

Comment: Please provide example how you initialized "pReturnType".

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem like this:

```
TypeMirror tm = fieldElement.asType();
    try {
        this.fieldType = Class.forName(tm.toString());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("unsupported datatype: " + tm.toString());
    }
```

tm.toString() has e.g. value: "java.lang.String"

Answer (score 0):

this is you want

```
System.out.println(pReturnType.getClass().getSimpleName());
```

its print **String[]**

but you want **String** you must give the index.

for example `System.out.println(pReturnType[i].getClass().getSimpleName());`

Comment: pReturnType is of type TypeMirror (which represetns an array), its not an array of TypeMirror.

Comment: anything. in your example **String[] foobar()** is given.  So i think it's a String. Anyway it's work like fallowing  `Object obj = Class.forName(your type).newInstance();`

Answer (score 0):

use `TypeVisitor`,
use this method to accept array type:

```
 /**
 * Visits an array type.
 * @param t the type to visit
 * @param p a visitor-specified parameter
 * @return  a visitor-specified result
 */
R visitArray(ArrayType t, P p);
```